# where is the error in my code in ajax or in django?

Tags: ajax, django, database, insert

i am trying to insert data into the database using django  and ajax.

i have a form that allow user to enter data into the text fileds and to choose between 2 options using radio button.

the problem is when i try to enter the path the system display the below error :

> ValueError at /addperson/ The view map.views.addperson didn't return
>   an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    boolChoice = (
        ("Male","M"),("Female","F")
        )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()
    gender = models.BooleanField(choices= boolChoice)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

## addPerson.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="hero__content">
   <form method="POST" class="form-style-9">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}


<ul>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<li>

    <h2>Add Member</h2>

</li>

<li>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="field-style field-split align-right" placeholder= "enter ur name " id="name"/>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="date" name="date" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder= " your birthdate" id="birthdate" />

</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"> Male<br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"> Female<br>

</li>

<li>
<textarea name="description" class="field-style" placeholder= "introduce yourself " id="description"></textarea>
</li>

<li>
<input type="submit" class="field-style field-full align-none" id="save" value="ADD" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
                 $(function(){
                    $('#save').on('click',function(e){
                        e.preventDefault()
                        name=$('#name').val()
                        birthdate=$('#birthdate').val()
                        description=$('#description').val()
                        radioValue = $("input[name = 'gender']:checked").val()
                        alert("radioValue =", radioValue)
     $.ajax({
      url:'/addperson/',
      method:'POST',
      data: {

                            na:name,
                            bi:birthdate,
                            de:description,
                            ra:radioValue
      },
      headers:{
       'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
      }
     }).done(function(msg) {
                        document.location = "/home.html"
                        alert('data saved')


     }).fail(function(err){
      alert('failed')
     })
    })
   })
  </script>
</li>
    </ul>
</form>

  </div>


{% endblock %}
```

## views.py

```
def addperson(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['na']
        birthdate = request.POST['bi']
        description=request.POST['de']
        radiovalue=request.POST['ra']

        person=Person.objects.create(
            name=name,
            date=birthdate,
            description=description,
            gender=radiovalue
        )
        person.save()
        return render(request,'./home.html')
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

from django.contrib import admin
from map import views as mapviews
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [

                       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
                       path('', mapviews.index),
                       path('addperson/',mapviews.addperson),

                      ]
```

Comment: Use if request.is_ajax():

Comment: The error is in your django view. You are trying to render a template in an ajax request .

Comment: return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

Comment: but i need to return  render  templates and not json format is this possible ?

Comment: i tried to return `HttpResponse( json.dumps(person), content_type="application/json" )`

but it still the same error

Comment: The reason you use ajax is to avoid page refresh and refresh only a part of the page

Comment: show your urls.py and try printing out request.method

Comment: so i printed out the `request.method`  but it display `GET`   i did not understand y and how to fix it ?

Comment: Your ajax request might not be going to the same url. Remove or add the backslash in the url in either the ajax request or in the urls.py

Comment: instead or #save.on click ,do on form.submit()

Answer (score -1):

i solved the problem because i was getting the form using **GET method**   so i create a path that allow the user to get the form by **POST method**